# Text won't center in header

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get the "Header" text to be centered and the icon to stay.

`text-align: center;` won't work for me.

Anyone can lead me in the right direction?

Thanks.

IMG:

[image]

```css
    .header {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      color: #fff;
      background: #333;
    }
    
    .header a {
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 32px;
      vertical-align: middle; 
    }
    
    #hamburger {
      color: white;
      font-size: 32px;
    }
    
    .menu {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="headerwrapper">
      <div class="header">
    
      <div class="menuWrap">
        <div class="menu open">
          <span id="hamburger" class="fas fa-bars hvr-grow"></span>
        </div>
          <a href="index.php">Header</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please can you show us the CSS for the menuWrap class because that is where you will want to do text-align=center (and not in the anchor text which is only as long as the header content).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centering can be done with `text-align: center;` on `.header`.

However, this will also affect your hamburger icon (which I replaced with an "X" below to make it visible), so apply `position: absolute` to its container `.menu` and use the `left` parameter to define the distance from the left border:

```css
.header {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      color: #fff;
      background: #333;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .header a {
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 32px;
    }
    
    #hamburger {
      color: white;
      font-size: 32px;
    }
    
    .menu {
      position: absolute;
      left: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="headerwrapper">
      <div class="header">
    
      <div class="menuWrap">
        <div class="menu open">
          <span id="hamburger" class="fas fa-bars hvr-grow">X</span>
        </div>
          <a href="index.php">Header</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly on desktop, however on mobile the text still does not align.

Comment: Then most likely you have some other CSS rules for the mobile version in media queries which you didn't post (?)

Comment: Don't mind my last comment, I forgot to remove the media query. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should put **text-align:center** into your `.header` class.

In addition to that you also should put `float:left;` property in the `.menu` class.

Here is the example:

```css
    .header {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      color: #fff;
      background: #333;
      text-align:center;
    }
    
    .header a {
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 32px;
      vertical-align: middle; 
    }
    
    #hamburger {
      color: white;
      font-size: 32px;
    }
    
    .menu {
      display: inline-block;
      float:left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="headerwrapper">
      <div class="header">
    
      <div class="menuWrap">
        <div class="menu open">
          <span id="hamburger" class="fas fa-bars hvr-grow">a</span>
        </div>
          <a href="index.php">Header</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This will center the entire header, hence the hamburger menu. This does not answer what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    text-align: center;
}

.header a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}

#hamburger {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}


.menu {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="headerwrapper">
      <div class="header">
    
      <div class="menuWrap">
        <div class="menu open">
          <span id="hamburger" class="fas fa-bars hvr-grow"></span>
        </div>
          <a href="index.php">Header</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **text-align** to your header class .header, it should look similar to this

```
 .header {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      color: #fff;
      background: #333;
       text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change Like This:**

```
.header a { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  //Other css...
}
```

```css
    .header {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      color: #fff;
      background: #333;
    }
    
    .header a {
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 32px;
      vertical-align: middle; 
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%);
    }
    
    #hamburger {
      color: white;
      font-size: 32px;
    }
    
    .menu {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="headerwrapper">
  <div class="header">

  <div class="menuWrap">

    <div class="menu open">
      <span id="hamburger" class="fas fa-bars hvr-grow">Icon</span>
    </div>

      <a href="index.php">Header</a>

  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```